# I want to disable a radius button

Tags: html, css

I want to disable this radius button, when I don't need it.
Like for example when I have two pages, it should be shown for one page and not for another.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
        <label class="">Radius:<span class="mandfield">*</span>
        </label>
        @*<input type="text" name="Radius" id="" />*@
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Radius, new { @id = "txtRadius" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the button use `hidden`

```html
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text" hidden />
```

And if you want to disable it use `disabled`

```html
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text" disabled />
```